# How to redirect to another url using react-router after promise?

Tags: reactjs, express, redirect, react-router

```
const submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(homeEmail === "") {
        alert("Please Provide A Valid E-Mail")
    }
    else {
        db.collection("Home E-Mail").add({
            email: homeEmail
        }).then(() => 
            <Redirect to="/thank-you" />
        ).catch(() => 
            alert("Oops! Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!")
        )

        setHomeEmail("")
    }
}
```

I've tried `<Redirect />` to redirect to '/thank-you' page after `.then` but there is no redirection.
How can I do this using `react-router`. If not possible using `react-router`, then how to do this using `express`

Comment: How about using `history.push('/thank-you')`

Comment: I think this post will answer your question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router).

Comment: Yes, some imperative navigation with `history.push` is in order, versus declarative with the `Redirect` component.

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke Thanks!
It resolved my issue!.
How can we achieve the same using express?

Comment: @Ayush Maybe you can send the route in form of response data, like, `route: '/thank-you` and for the frontend URL you can save it in some `config` file. `${config.Domain}/res.route`. The `res.route` will obviously depend upon how you'll resolve data coming from express

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke Thanks! I'll try this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<Redirect />`, you can use `history.push('/thank-you')` to redirect after your promise is resolved.